# NavBar Scrolling down with page

Tags: html, navbar

**My questions is how can I make my NavBar go down with the page using JQuery?**

*My code:*

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="navBar.css">
       <title>NavBAR</title>
    </head>
<body>

<div class='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
       <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1 style="font-size:30000%;">SomeText</h1>

</body>
<html>
```

*If you need to know something more than tell me because im only a beginner!*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using both of jquery and css.

If you want to do it using jquery, you should use **scroll** event of **window**

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  $(".cssmenu").css("top", $(window).scrollTop() + 50);
});
```

```css
.cssmenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
       <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1 style="font-size:300px;">SomeText</h1>
```

But if you want to do it using css, you should set it's position **fixed**.

```css
.cssmenu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top : 10px;
  background-color: Gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
       <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1 style="font-size:300px;">SomeText</h1>
```